# Apt-removing Viber - 385 GB will be removed

Tags: apt, package-management

Recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. The desktop Viber app for Ubuntu got broken. I would like to remove it now. However when trying to remove it using `apt` getting:

```
sudo apt remove viber
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  viber
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 385 GB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

When tried to run a new DEB downloaded from official website, it says there is fragmentation error.

I have already found and removed all Viber-related files via:

```
sudo find / -name "viber*" 2>/dev/null
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8/usr/share/icons/breeze/apps/48/viber.svg
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/apps/48/viber.svg
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32/usr/share/icons/breeze/apps/48/viber.svg
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/apps/48/viber.svg
/home/<user-name>/Downloads/viber.deb
```

It feels like running `apt remove` will wipe something important, like the whole system partition.

### Question

Is it safe to run `apt remove` in this case? Is it possible that the app has been already removed, in this case how to clean up the system from registries - so it knows the app has been removed.

---

Viber was installed using DEB file downloaded from the official website. Snap does not have official Viber package.

Also:

```
sudo snap list | grep viber*
sudo snap list | grep blender*
blender                            2.93.9                       2255   2.93lts/stable   blenderfoundation*  classic
```

Comment: I ran standard distro-upgrade procedure from 21.10 to 22.04. Viber is currently broken anyway on 22.04 because of NVidia + Wayland issue. Asking about general approach - if it is possible to remove something from `apt` so it does not bother me. Also are there any steps to take some diagnostics to make sure all disc are in correct state etc.

Comment: Oh, looks like I have found something: https://linuxx.info/version-viber-for-gnu-linux-requires-320-gb-of-free-space/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after accidently finding this article: https://linuxx.info/version-viber-for-gnu-linux-requires-320-gb-of-free-space/.

I have simply ran `apt remove viber`:

```
sudo apt remove viber 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  viber
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 385 GB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'viber' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 195039 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing viber (16.1.0.37) ...
```

No disks were erased. Looks like the developers haven't fixed the bug with the size yet.